# Ionic Controller Function Variable Out Of Scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Based on the tabs template from Ionic. When I click a button(ng-click), it calls the function func()

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.number=3; 
    $scope.func=function(){ 
        number=number+123;
      }  
});
```

When I try to run func(). Chrome reports the following.

```
ReferenceError: number is not defined
```

I think it is because that func() cannot find the variable number. Is there a way I can modify data in a function?

Comment: `$scope.number = $scope.number + 123`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there isn't a variable called `number` in existence. That would only be true if you had put `var number` somewhere to declare it.

To modify the `number` value you *have* declared, make sure you reference the same object that it's a part of.

```
$scope.func = function() {
  $scope.number = number + 123;
  // or $scope.number += 123;
};
```